# Authorize Google analytics data from a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to authorize an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app to Google analytics data API.

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    
    var client = await BetaAnalyticsDataClient.CreateAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    var request = new RunReportRequest
    {
        Property = "properties/" + XXXXX,
        Dimensions = {new Dimension {Name = "date"},},
        Metrics = {new Metric {Name = "totalUsers"},new Metric {Name = "newUsers"}},
        DateRanges = {new DateRange {StartDate = "2021-04-01", EndDate = "today"},},
    };

    var response = await client.RunReportAsync(request);
}
```

The authorization goes though as would be expected; I am getting an access token back.

[image]

I cant seem to figure out how to apply the credentials to the `BetaAnalyticsDataClient`.

When I run it without applying it to the `BetaAnalyticsDataClient`, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

I am not currently using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as it is configured in `programs.cs`. I don't see the need to have client id and secret configured in `program.cs` plus having an added env var.

Why isn't it just picking up the authorization already supplied with the controller runs?

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
        // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
        // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
        o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
        // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
        o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
```

Is there an alternate method for authorizing with a web app that I have not been able to find. I did do some dinging in the source code I can't seem to find a method to apply this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite a bit of digging i managed to find that it was possible to create my own client builder and apply the credentials there.

```
var clientBuilder = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder()
    {
        Credential = await auth.GetCredentialAsync()
    };
    var client = await clientBuilder.BuildAsync();
```

Hope this helps someone else.